# Thermal Question About Heat Management

Tags: hvac, vent

I have a house that has a loft. The loft has a flap at the highest point that has a turbine cut in the roof deck. On hot days the turbine will spin sometimes very fast as hot air escapes.

My question is two fold:

1. should I leave that flap open during the day, even if I am going to use A/C part of the time?
2. or should I leave it open only until the first time the house has filled with cool air then close it?

The logic of #1 is that the A/C will push cold air in and the hot air will be forced up and out, lessening the work the condenser will have to do. But 2 makes me think that once the structure has cool air in it, leaving the flap open might just invite the condenser to suck hot air in through the turbine.

So looking for optimal strategy: close, leave open until cool then close, always open.

Comment: The inside of the house is directly vented to the outside? That is not just an attic vent?

Comment: @BrownRedHawk The loft has a vent to the outside, that is in the attic.

Comment: If your AC unit draws in a small amount of fresh air I would leave it open to help push out the hot air (some systems have a small duct to bring in fresh air some do not). If you don't have a small amount of fresh air coming in as the house cools it will draw hot air from the roof in as the air is cooled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "loft" as generally understood by me is an elevated living platform/area that is part of the main living quarters, i.e. **not** in an attic. So my presumption (as stated/queried by BrownRedhawk) is that, yes, "the inside of the house is directly vented to the outside" by a roof mounted turbine ventilator.

Roof mounted turbine ventilators are designed to remove hot air from a space when caused to spin by wind outside of the space. When installed correctly (perfectly level) they can spin quite fast and move quite a bit of air even with a slight breeze. Their intended purpose is *not* to spin due to rising hot air from inside the space.

- Question #1- your logic is faulty. Your home AC does not "push cold air in...and hot air out", it circulates the air in the space across a heat exchanger, which removes the heat from that air. Leaving the turbine "in service" with the AC on will make it harder for the unit to cool the mass of air because of continual air movement through the ventilator. It would be like running your auto A/C with the windows down.
- Question#2- your logic here is also faulty, for the same reasons as stated above.

**OPTIMAL STRATEGY**- take the turbine out of service (close the flap) whenever you are running the AC. You should do the same whenever you *want* to retain heat in the home.

Comment: I know how an HVAC system works. Jesus. Gotta love communities. Have you ever read about thermodynamics? when air goes into a space colder air sinks in that space. If there is hotter air it rises, if you add air to a space that has a vent in the top, some air will go out the top. That's not faulty logic. I know that the system circulates air.

Comment: BTW, you are saying my logic is faulty and then suggesting one of the strategies I proposed! :) So I didn't even understand my own good idea? I am fine with that...

Comment: Your logic is faulty but I'm not trying to insult you. *Again* you are saying that you are ADDING air. You are not. Any break in your thermal envelope will work against your efforts to condition the space, whether it is cooling or heating. Ok, I guess I could have just put the word "close" as my answer, but I was trying to explain my understanding of the situation. Plus your statement "The loft has a vent to the outside, that is in the attic" did not make sense to me.

Comment: Of course warm air rises and cooler/drier air is more dense and will stay lower (yes, moist air is *lighter* than dry air). That does not mean the warm air will get "pushed" out of your roof opening.

Comment: I try to explain my answers, right or wrong. If you want single-word responses that you can rebut out-of-hand because they have no information behind them then maybe this is the wrong forum for you.

Comment: I was not complaining about the number of words, the faulty logic' comment not once but twice was ludicrous. Don't tell me whether this forum is right for me or not, unless you are the moderator. I have been on a bazillion public community sites. I say with confidence users on most of them would find your heavy handed response offensive.

Comment: Technically you are right that saying 'adding air' is probably not correct because air is going out through the return of course. What I was saying was simply that if you take a chamber and put colder, denser air into it, it will take space from the warmer air. Again, I agree with the verdict. I proposed it as a likely conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of vents are common. However, understand how they work: they suck out hot air that's in the attic, and that removed air needs to be replaced by air that enters from somewhere else. If your attic was built correctly, the make-up air enters through soffit vents. If your attic was built incorrectly or shoddily (which is common), the make-up air will be pulled from the inhabited part of your house. If this is happening, you need to air-seal the barrier layer (usually the ceiling) between the attic and the inhabited part of the house. In many houses there are a variety of ways for air in the house to leak into the attic:

- Ducts or mechanical equipment located in the attic
- Attic pull-down staircase door that has not been air-sealed
- Bath vents that have not been air-sealed
- Chimneys and flues that have not been air-sealed
- Ceiling lights and electrical boxes that have not been air-sealed
- Holes drilled in wall top plates for electrical wires that have not been air-sealed

All of those can let air in your house into the attic, causing the roof vents to pull air that you've paid good money to condition into the attic where it's not doing anyone any good.